# Replace NaN in pandas DataFrame with random strings without using fillna

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, fillna

I have a pandas DataFrame like below

```
      NAME      EMAIL      HEIGHT      WEIGHT

1     jlka       NaN        170          70

2     qwer     eee@ttt      180          80

3     ioff       NaN        175          75

4     iowu     iou@add      170          60
```

And I want to replace NaN in 'EMAIL' column with random strings with no duplicates, which does not necessarily contain @.

I have tried to make a def which generates random strings but NaNs were replaced with the same random string since I used 'fillna' method after all.

It seems like, and as I saw other Q$As, def in fillna works only once and replace all the NaN with the same values or strings came out from the def.

Should I try 'for' sentence to replace them one by one?

Or is there a more Pythonic way to replace them?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the problem with using None when there isn't email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
import random
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['aaa','bbb','CCC'],
    'Email': [nan,'ddd',nan]})

def processNan (x):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(10))

df['Email'] = df['Email'].apply(lambda x: processNan(x) if x is nan else x)
```

Comment: Sorry I am too new here. I marked it to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.util.testing.rands_array`, passing it the length of your desired string as the first (nchars) argument and the number of `NaN`s as the second (size) argument:

```
df.loc[df.EMAIL.isna(), "EMAIL"] = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, sum(df.EMAIL.isnull()))      

>>> df                                                                                              

   NAME       EMAIL  HEIGHT  WEIGHT
1  jlka  YxzVaC38uw     170      70
2  qwer     eee@ttt     180      80
3  ioff  33kyDArtip     175      75
4  iowu     iou@add     170      60
```

`pd.util.testing.rand_array` could be replaced with any function that returns a list or array with a specific size.